# XPATH select second item (not child)

Tags: xpath

I was trying to get only the first element:

```
<xml>
  <title>xpath.playground.fontoxml.com</title>
  <summary>This is a learning tool for XML, XPath and XQuery.</summary>
  <tips>
    <tip id='1' name='hello'>You can edit everything on the left</tip>
    <tip id='examples'>You can access more examples from a menu in the top right</tip>
    <tip id='permalink'>Another button there lets you share your test using an URL</tip>
  </tips>
  <tips>
    <tip id='2' name='hello'>You can edit everything on the left</tip>
    <tip id='examples'>You can access more examples from a menu in the top right</tip>
    <tip id='permalink'>Another button there lets you share your test using an URL</tip>
  </tips>
</xml>
```

This is the XPATH, im trying to get one element from all with name='hello'

```
//*[@name='hello'][1]
```

but it returns both `<tip id='1' name='hello'>` and `<tip id='2' name='hello'>`

my expectation was `//*[@name='hello'][1]` returns the element with id=1 and `//*[@name='hello'][2]` returns the element with id=2

how do I get this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
(//*[@name='hello'])[2]
```